# Upgraded to Joomla 2.5.6 - "Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail"

Tags: joomla, sendmail, joomla2.5, phpmailer, php

After upgrading to Joomla 2.5 so that I could use the latest version of Virtuemart, the system emails no longer work.

I have checked the Sendmail path against the entry in the php.ini file. (/usr/sbin/sendmail).

If I try Joomla's Sendmail option I get `Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail.`

If I try PHP Mail I get `Could not instantiate mail function.`

Also, I can no longer upload templates:

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Warning: Failed to move file!
```

I understand that I can 777 all the relevant folders to get this to work, but this isn't acceptable. Also, this certainly doesn't help with the mail problem.

File permissions appear the same as they were previously. What does my web host need to change to allow Joomla to do what it did before my upgrade?

Thanks,

Andy

[edit] I copied the site, exported the SQL and migrated to a different server to test. Everything worked fine, so I can confirm that the problem isn't with my Joomla install, but with the server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web host have resolved the issue. I'm quoting their solution here:

"In servers global php.ini file we've disabled some functions for security reasons, so to override this you can simply create a custom php.ini file under the document root folder (under public_html folder) and update/change/enable the values in order to get your website working.

Please note that this is done for security to avoid any external hacks/malwares etc.

You'll just need to copy/paste the php.ini (uploaded in public_html folder) to the directory location of other domain accounts where you are running application.

Even if turn off the values in local php.ini the script/application will work properly as it override the values in the globally php.ini file. Please note that since suPHP is enabled on the server hence users have option to create their own custom php.ini file and override the actual values set in globally.

I've uploaded the custom php.ini file under public_html folder and then sendmail started working."

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with Joomla 2.5.8.
I Just changed  in Global Cnf-Server-Mail settings.
SendMail changed to PHP Mail and no problem anymore..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not set any permissions to 777, it's necessary and a security risk. Are you sure that your permissions are correct? Go in to the admin, then Site > System Information > Directory Permissions and make sure that everything is writable. Folders should be 755, files should be 644.

If you had FTP mode enabled before, you might want to look there. However, rather than using FTP mode, you really should use a hosts that runs PHP in CGI mode. Not only is it more secure, but it generally solves most permission issues.

Comment: Agreed on the file permissions. Looked at System Information > Directory Permissions. Says Log and Temp directories are unwritable, but when I ftp in they are 755 (files are 644). I even tried changing /tmp and /logs folder permissions to 777 and System Information still says 'unwritable' How can this be?

Comment: System Information >PHP information says 'Server API:CGI/FastCGI'

Comment: Changed to logs and tmp directories in web root and now they're writable. Now getting:
        JFolder::create: Could not create directory
        Unable to create destination
Mail problem same as before.

Comment: Can you install templates? You might also want to install a clean version of 2.5.x to see if it has the same problem before spending too much more time tracking this down.

Comment: I can't install templates either. Installed a clean 2.5.6 and had exactly the same errors. Directory permissions all writable. One thing I noticed with the installation, for the server PHP settings there were 2 recommendations that weren't met. 'Safe Mode'and 'Magic Quotes GPC' were recommended Off but were actually On. Thanks for your time on this, @Brent I really appreciate it.

Comment: Neither of those should be a problem, but it is an issue if a clean install is not working. This means it's time to look at the server setup/configuration. What version of PHP are you using? Do you have access to the complete error logs?

Comment: Bang-on. It was an issue with PHP and the web host finally resolved it. Posted their answer below. Will accept it as the answer when I can, hopefully help others.

Answer (score 0):

Is your hosting solution compatible with Joomla requirements : mysql and php version?

If Yes:
 - Check Joomla folders owner with your ftp client
 - Install manually upgrade patch from 2.5 to 2.5.x (maybe some files were corrupted during update process)
 - Try chmod 777 on required folders

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mailer setting in global configuration..

Joomla administrator->Site->Global Configuration->Server->Mail Settings

- Change the mailer option to sendmail and then check
- Some times during upgrade the patch files may be corrupted or lost. May be this also caused this issue.
- **JFolder::create: Could not create directory** this Waring was occurred due to folder permission. Check ur folder permission.